# Printing multiple formviews when one formview is empty gives incomplete results

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a page with two formviews.  The sub below works fine for printing when when both formviews contain data but when the second formview is empty I get only partial output of the first formview.  The first part of the sub (If FormView2.DataItemCount = 0 Then) is where the problem occurs. Strangely, if the first part is run (without the "If" statement) it correctly prints the first formview only, ignoring the second one.  In this case, the first formview should have 17 rows of data but only 2 are printed.  Before I get older and greyer does anybody have any suggestions?  Thanks!

**Of Note: I changed default browsers from Explorer to Firefox and the program works fine.  There is obviously something here Explorer doesn't like.**

```
Protected Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    If FormView2.DataItemCount = 0 Then
        FormView1.DataBind()
        FormView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
        FormView1.Attributes("style") = "border-collapse:separate"
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        FormView1.RenderControl(hw)
        Dim gridHTML As String = sw.ToString().Replace("""", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "")
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){")
        sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0")
        sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');")
        sb.Append("printWin.document.write(""")
        Dim style As String = "<style type = 'text/css'>thead {display:table-header-group;} tfoot{display:table-footer-group;}</style>"
        sb.Append(style & gridHTML)
        sb.Append(""");")
        sb.Append("printWin.document.close();")
        sb.Append("printWin.focus();")
        sb.Append("printWin.print();")
        sb.Append("printWin.close();")
        sb.Append("};")
        sb.Append("</script>")
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "GridPrint", sb.ToString())
        FormView1.DataBind()
    End If

    If FormView2.DataItemCount <> 0 Then
        FormView1.DataBind()
        FormView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
        FormView1.Attributes("style") = "border-collapse:separate"
        FormView2.DataBind()
        FormView2.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
        FormView2.Attributes("style") = "border-collapse:separate"
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        FormView1.RenderControl(hw)
        FormView2.RenderControl(hw)
        Dim gridHTML As String = sw.ToString().Replace("""", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "")
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){")
        sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0")
        sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');")
        sb.Append("printWin.document.write(""")
        Dim style As String = "<style type = 'text/css'>thead {display:table-header-group;} tfoot{display:table-footer-group;}</style>"
        sb.Append(style & gridHTML)
        sb.Append(""");")
        sb.Append("printWin.document.close();")
        sb.Append("printWin.focus();")
        sb.Append("printWin.close();")
        sb.Append("};")
        sb.Append("</script>")
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){")
        sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0")
        sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');")
        sb.Append("printWin.document.write(""")
        Dim style1 As String = "<style type = 'text/css'>thead {display:table-header-group;} tfoot{display:table-footer-group;}</style>"
        sb.Append(style & gridHTML)
        sb.Append(""");")
        sb.Append("printWin.document.close();")
        sb.Append("printWin.focus();")
        sb.Append("printWin.print();")
        sb.Append("printWin.close();")
        sb.Append("};")
        sb.Append("</script>")
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "GridPrint", sb.ToString())
        FormView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a posting that gave me the answer, and a rather simple solution that works in both Explorer and Firefox.  I deleted all of the above and changed it to what is below:

```
Protected Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "popup", "<script language=javascript>javascript:window.print();</script>")

End Sub
```